# post method 405 error in bottle python

Tags: python, html, bottle

I trying to use post method, but getting error 405. This is my python code:

```
@route('/')
def home():
    return template('driver_homepage(2)')
@route('/submit' , methods = ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT'])
     def calculate():
     zone  = request.form['zone']
     #...... 
     ans = eligorithm.Estimation
     return template('driver_finalpage-2')
     #return template('driver_finalpage-2', ans=ans)
run(reloader=True)
```

when I click on my calculate button on HTML page, instead of going to driver_finalpage-2(tis page is in .tpl and .html, I m using .tpl here) showing an error.
HTML form:

```
<form method="post" action="/submit">     
<!-- ...(in here taking input in various fields) -->
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Calculate">
```

Please help.

Comment: pls fomat your code first

Comment: done formatting

Answer (score 1):

You may try to change `methods` to `method` as follows

```
@route('/submit' , method=['GET', 'POST', 'PUT'])
def calculate():
    ...
```